# Codeigniter: TinyMCE image manager dynamic image paths

Tags: php, codeigniter, tinymce

I have installed TinyMCE into my codeigniter build, and I have included the image manager.

In the image manager plugin (which is saved in the public/assets folder) there is a php config file which defines the image & file path constants.

```
define('DIR_IMAGES', 'images/path/here'); etc
```

The problem I have is I need the path to be dynamic depending on some data in the database, such as template_name, but I dont know how to include the right files into the config file so I can view the dynamic info.

So if the user has a template_name saved then I need the path to be

```
define('DIR_IMAGES', $template_name.'images/path/here');
```

I have also defined the template_name in a constant in core/MY_Controller.php so if I could access that variable that would be easier than doing a query to the DB but either way will work.

Can someone give me a hand with this, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just custom tinymce image but not using TinyMCE image manager.

but I use the tutorial from the link below.

[How-to implement a custom file browser](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/How-to_implement_a_custom_file_browser)

```
<!-- Start tinymce custom -->
<script type="text/javascript">
 tinyMCE.init({

  <!-- 
      your tiny mce init here 
   --->


   <!-- custom file browser callback -->
   file_browser_callback : 'myFileBrowser',
 });

function myFileBrowser (field_name, url, type, win) {
  // this is your dynamic image path
  var cmsURL = "<?php echo base_url() ?>admin/media/select_image";  <== you can set as you wish
if (cmsURL.indexOf("?") < 0) {
  //add the type as the only query parameter
  cmsURL = cmsURL + "?type=" + type;
   }
else {
  //add the type as an additional query parameter
   // (PHP session ID is now included if there is one at all)
cmsURL = cmsURL + "&type=" + type;
}

   tinyMCE.activeEditor.windowManager.open({
file : cmsURL
,width : 600
,height : 600
,resizable : "yes"
,inline : "yes"
,close_previous : "yes"
,popup_css : true // Disable TinyMCE's default popup CSS
}, {
window : win,
input : field_name
});
return false;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but the question was more how can I access my codeigniter global variables and constants within the TinyMCE library config file

Answer (score 0):

Add a "data-" attribute to your tinymce  element and echo your desired url from there. Then in tinymce activeEditor, access that data- attribute value.

Textarea

```
<textarea name="description" class="tinymceDescription" data-uploadLink="<?php echo DIR_IMAGES; ?>" ></textarea>
```

TinyMce

```
tinymce.init({
    // other settings here


    //either use this if you are uploading automatically.
    images_upload_url: $(tinymce.activeEditor.targetElm).attr("data-uploadLink"),


    //or use this if you want to override tinymce auto upload.
    images_upload_handler: function (blobInfo, success, failure) {
        var xhr, formData;

        var uploadLink = $(tinymce.activeEditor.targetElm).attr("data-uploadLink");

        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.withCredentials = false;
        xhr.open('POST', uploadLink);

        xhr.onload = function () {
            var json;

            if (xhr.status != 200) {
                failure('HTTP Error: ' + xhr.status);
                return;
            }

            json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

            if (!json || typeof json.location != 'string') {
                failure(xhr.responseText);
                return;
            }

            success(json.location);
        };

        formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', blobInfo.blob(), blobInfo.filename());

        xhr.send(formData);
    }
});
```

The point here is to show you how i got a dynamic upload url into tinymce from the currently selected tinymce instance. The way you upload is your choice which i hope you know how to handle. But ether way, i have provide both the automatic and custom examples.